# refinerycms-inquiries generator throwing regular expression error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, content-management-system, refinerycms

I am trying to generate the refinery:inquiries like described [here](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-inquiries).

However, when I run the generator, I get following error:

```
rails generate refinery:inquiries
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:39:in `check_options_validity': The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option? (ArgumentError)
```

I notice that a lot of the Refinery Engines are very outdated. This one however, was last updated 3 months so hoping that it may be okay but just a little hiccup happening.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to the maintainer (@parndt) as he clued me in that I was not including the Gem correctly for Rails 4.2 prerelease support.

```
gem "refinerycms-inquiries", git: "https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-inquiries", branch: "master"
```